# Referring to an Image variable by String

Tags: c#, string, variables

Good day, I have some images variables in my code e.g. `Image1` `Image2`. I want to create an image array for later reference and thought that an Image array would be too memory consuming. Can I create a string array instead and fill it out with elemnets like `Image1` , `Image2` .... And then somehow refer to the  `Image Image1` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At best I would suggest a `Dictionary<String, Image>` but either way you are going to have to store the image unless you are wanting to fetch them dynamically.

[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then you can add them like this

```
Dictionary<String, Image> images = new Dictionary<String, Image>();
images.Add("Image1", Image1);
```

Then when you need to look it up you can simply go

```
Image myImage;
images.TryGetValue("Image1", out myImage);
```

You can also index the dictionary but I prefer the above when dealing with literals.

Comment: +1 He has already stored them as variable, so your advice to use a `Dictionary` instead should work fine. One or two words/links to show how to use it would be nice though.